# Is it ok (is it really bad) to make many small queries in a loop?

Tags: php, mysql

**Skip that if you value your time.**

I am making a website that has a special "control panel" for a few (less than 20) people. It is a calendar where you can see which days aren't occupied yet and book  "events" to them if it's needed. Panel uses php and mysql database to hold usernames, events etc. It is pretty much finished, but i noticed that i need to check if exact same data isn't stored in database already (it wouldn't cause problems, but it would be better to avoid redundancy).

First solution i came up with is just add a query (checking if there is an appointment in the time) to every added row (they are added in a loop) and do the INSERT only if checking query returned 0 rows.

**You can really ignore anything higher than that, i added explanation only to clarify situation more.**

**My question is:** Is it really bad for the server if there are many small queries run in a loop, or that doesn't really matter because queries are not that hard for a server? Maybe it really matters and i should for example run one, bigger query and save it into an array or something?

It probably doesn't matter but i am using object oriented setup from [there](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/using-php-with-mysql-the-right-way/17)

I am asking mostly to expand my knowledge, because this utility will be used only by one person anyways, so server will keep up even if it is not really efficient.

Comment: This question cannot be answered. You already know that it is generally a bad idea to do what you ask. Is it *really bad*? Well, try it and benchmark the performance of your application. Ultimately, the decision is yours. How fast would you like your app to run?

Comment: To execute query in a loop is a very bad practices, it doesn't matter you have small queries or large due to the speed mismatch in db query and php. Don't use instead you can use unique index on table and can apply exception handling or you can use INSERT IGNORE in case there is possibility of duplicacy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too long for a comment.

Is it a really bad idea?  Depends on your definition of bad.  In general, multiple such queries are more expensive.  And multiple queries introduce more opportunities for race conditions.  Doesn't sound like a "good" idea to me.

More importantly, though, is checking for duplicates in the application.  You have a database and can use the database to prevent duplicates.  This is called a "unique" constraint or a unique index (the former is implemented using the latter).  Your question doesn't have enough information to make a concrete suggestion, but that sounds like what you really need.

Comment: Is it possible to set pair of column as unique? So 1 can repeat, 2 can repeat, but exact pair of 1 and 2 cannot?
And what happens if i try to add duplicate of unique value? Will it just not do anything without error?

Comment: @TheSorter . . . You should ask another question, describing what you are trying to do (prevent, I guess) with sample data.